# How is this folder redirection to a drive letter done?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mfc

I was wondering how does a [utility like this one](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/visual-subst.html) redirects a folder to a driver letter?

PS. I need this done with C/C++/MFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably uses [DefineDosDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363904%28VS.85%29.aspx), as an ordinary `subst` command does.

Comment: Thanks. Is it supposed to run as some sort of a device driver?

Comment: No, it's callable from a user space.